# How to create primary settings in one file and create another file using first file in plantuml?

Tags: plantuml

I have puml file like this

```
@startuml

'Start - This needs to be created in the 'primary.puml' file.
skinparam defaultFontName Arial
skinparam sequenceArrowThickness 2
skinparam roundcorner 20
skinparam maxMessageSize 300
skinparam ParticipantPadding 80
skinparam BoxPadding 80
skinparam defaultFontSize 12

skinparam sequence {
ArrowColor Black

LifeLineBorderColor #1A1A1A
LifeLineBackgroundColor #B3B3B3

ParticipantBorderColor #24245a
ParticipantBackgroundColor #24245a
ParticipantFontColor #A9DCDF

ActorBorderColor #4257A0
ActorBackgroundColor #4257A0
ActorFontColor Black
}

skinparam SequenceMessage {
Padding 2 
Margin  2
}
'End- This needs to be created in the 'primary.puml' file.
```

And inherit primary.puml file in another puml files . So, I can centralize the settings in a single location and have them applied to all other diagrams. Any changes made in the primary file will affect all associated child PlantUML files.

example :

```
!include primary.puml

@startuml
actor User as A 
participant UI as B  
participant DB as C
@enduml
```

I'm uncertain whether this can be accomplished by creating a project in Visual Studio Code and creating child files using the primary file. Please let me  know if this can be achieved ?

Comment: I think you only have to put the `!include primary.puml` on the line after `@startuml` and make sure that the files are in the same directtory.

Comment: > I'm uncertain whether this can be accomplished by creating a project in Visual > Studio Code and creating child files using the primary file. Please let me know > if this can be achieved ?

What exactly do you mean @ANR? Including separate PlantUML files is not IDE-specific. Do you mean, you need to place the files in different directories? Or do you mean, let the files transitively include each other, e.g. a.puml is included in b.puml, which is includes in c.puml?